# Linux RAID5 array error

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have two RAID5 arrays, 1 array for `/boot` and for `/`. The arrays both consist of three partitions:
MD0: /boot
MD1: /

My problem is, if I detached a disk (disappear) then mdadm prints that a drive went wrong. Okay no problem, but this message only from MD1. And the MD0 doesn't say anything. Look this:

```
md1 : active raid5 sda2[3](F) sdb2[2] sdc2[1]
      7383040 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [_UU]

md0 : active raid5 sda1[3] sdb1[2] sdc1[1]
      995328 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
```

The sda drive disappeared but only in MD1 array. I can detached the drive from MD1 with the following command: mdadm /dev/md1 -r detached. Because the drive not existing.

But I can't detached from MD0:

```
mdadm: hot remove failed for 8:1: Device or resource busy
```

Because, the mdadm didn't say the sda drive went wrong. But why?

Comment: It is a bit safer to add a replacement drive to the RAID before you remove the defective one.

Answer (score 1):

Linux’s MD stack finds a device failed when it tries to read or write it and the operation fails. As long as it does not try to read or write in `/boot`, it may not figure out that `sda1` failed.

You cannot detach it while it is not failed, but you can force it to fail manually with `mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1`.

Comment: > Linux’s MD stack finds a device failed when it tries to read or write
> it and the operation fails. As long as it does not try to read or
> write in /boot, it may not figure out that sda1 failed.
Yes, it's true. Thanks. The `mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1`command not working because the sda drive not exists. (No such file or directory)

Comment: Try to copy some file to the `/boot` directory.

Comment: @Chraze Possibly the software responsible for creating inodes in `/dev` has noticed the drive is absent and removed the inodes. If that's the case you can create them again manually with `mknod`.